# Precisamos das tags [syntax-error] e [undefined]?

Tags: debate, tags, tag-específica

Hoje me deparei com as tags [syntax-error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-error) e [undefined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined)

A descrição da tag [syntax-error](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax-error) é:

> Em Ciências da Computação, Syntax Errors são erros na sintaxe na sequência de caracteres ou tokens intendidos pela linguagem de programação que os definiram. Em linguagens compiladas erros de sintaxe ocorrem estritamente quando da compilação do programa, o qual é impedido até todos os erros de ...

Pra começar a tag nem fala de como usar no site, quem a criou se preocupou apenas em dizer "o que é" e não quando usar e se olharem melhor, ficou ainda três pontos no final `...`, ou seja a descrição deve ser um Copy+Paste e pelo limite do campo não coube.

Creio também que se é para discutir alguma "teoria" ou o que é `sintaxe-error` a tag [sintaxe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sintaxe) (que já existe) é mais do que suficiente.

E não consigo ver uso para ela, a não ser que fosse alguma pergunta de teoria sobre o problema exato, mas só uma pergunta que vi nessa tag era sobre algo assim, as outras eram erros de sintaxe mesmo, o que geralmente são perguntas fechadas.

Pra tag [undefined](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined) também não vejo utilidade, geralmente é **erro de digitação**, e se houver alguma pergunta especifica sobre teoria ou o que é "undefined" de fato, nem precisaria de uma tag, a pergunta em si seria o foco já.

O que acham? Elas tem utilidade para a comunidade?

Comment: Eu acho as duas desnecessárias. Ninguém clica numa tag [tag:undefined] pra tentar procurar algo, hahahahahahaha

Comment: A tag syntax-error não faz muito sentido ;)

Comment: @gato essas tags são tipo humor inglês, NONSENSE (absurdo, irreal, sem sentido :P)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento de fato xD

Comment: Alguém chegou a alguma conclusão daqui? Remover `syntax-error` e colocar como sinônimo de `sintaxe`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado se chegar a 10 upvotes de diferença contra downvotes e não tiver mais manifestações eu vou remover ambas manualmente mesmo :D